# do i need json.js file?

Tags: asp.net, json

Some part of my web application will require json. I plan to make those pages only accessible to IE8 and up, Firefox 3 and up, Chrome 4 and up, and Safari 4 and up. I plan to use jquery to convert strings to json. Do all these browsers handle the conversion of json objects to strings? If so, do I still need to include the json.js file? I'm using asp.net 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have the [Yahoo! UI Library JSON file](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/JSON.js.html).

If that's the case, or even not the case, you'd simply have to determine whether any methods/functions in that file are actually being used. That'll determine whether it's safe to exclude from your web application.

Comment: @frenchie - having jQuery doesn't matter too much. What's important is determining whether your project *requires the Yahoo library* to function properly. What happens when you simply comment-out the `<script>` reference for json.js? Does your site continue to work as expected?

Comment: If all i need is to convert a json object to a string, can the browsers I plan on supporting handle that without any other library needed?